# Virtualbox very unstable

Tags: virtualbox

For some reason on Linux, I've had a lot of problems with VMs running a gui. First it was with a windows vm freezing regularly, now I'm trying to install Kali linux and the install fails. As soon as I boot from the iso install disk, the screen shows a single cursor and doesn't move at all for at least hours. I've tried combinations of using a fixed disk size with plenty of resources. I've tried disabling IO APIC but at least in this example, I can not boot from the iso and install an OS.

What should I try next? And is it just me, or is Virtualbox very unstable?

Note I've been trying the linux 2.6 64bit kernel with an accompanying iso of 64 bit.

Also note that the iso is definitely intact and not corrupted. I've just used the same iso to boot from usb and it works perfectly on a laptop.

Comment: first check that your CPU supports VT-X or AMD-V, and enable it in your bios. If your cpu  doesn't support them, or they are disabled, you cannot run 64bit guest OSes.  Then confirm that your VM is configured as shown here (but select 64bit): http://kanishkashowto.com/2013/09/03/how-to-install-kali-linux-in-virtualbox-step-by-step-guide/. Also, why such an old kernel? Last, virtualbox has a lot of flux between versions. every once in a while a version comes out that breaks my rig, and the next one or the one after fixes it.

Comment: You might wish to purchase VMware Workstation and try that.  I think that it is more stable than Virtualbox anyway.  Of course, you get what you pay for.

Comment: @FrankThomas actually that may not actually confirm kernel version. just going by the dropdown options when you go to create a new VM (before you've even chosen an iso). looks like that could be just a naming thing so you can identify the machine.

Comment: @FrankThomas i've also installed using the options in that guide to no avail. machine still hangs on install.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Vbox for awhile & I did experience similar effects at the beginning. That said, over time the situation has improved & I am quite satisfied with the installation which I am using at the moment. My suggestion would be to update the virtual host system. I personally run a Debian Wheezy 7.6 (Kernel 3.2.0) at the moment & I try to stay as actual as is possible. It has been my experience that this is the best way to avoid problems.

Hope this was helpful.

Just as an afterthought, have you tried running headless VMs & using RDP or VNC to access the GUI.

> vboxmanage list vms (to get the uid)
>
> vboxheadless --startvm uid

Comment: I'm actually running a later version than you. Debian 7.7 with 3.2.0-4 kernel.

Comment: Well then we are using the same kernel. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.